# Add charset to codec (play framework:scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I just write code like this.  When it's content-type is "text/html", it maybe doesn't include with "charset=utf-8" and my page is broken.

```
val feedUrl = "http://www.google.com"

def get(file:String) = Action.async {
  WS.url(feedUrl+file).get().map { response =>
    Ok(response.body) as response.header("content-type").getOrElse("*/*")
  }
}
```

How do I add charset option with this code?